# Should I place my preamble on a .tex file or on a .sty file

Tags: packages, input, preamble

I'm writing my thesis and have decided to place my preamble with packages and custom new commands and macros in there in order to have a cleaner `main.tex` file.

I have placed my preamble in a file named `mypreamble.sty`.

### Is this best practice to write a .sty?

It compiles as expected and no errors are shown.

Should I place my preamble on a `preamble.tex` and call it with `\input{preamble.tex}`?

#### Here's a minimal working example:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
{\thechapter}
{0.5em}
{\MakeUppercase}
[]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0em}{*2}{*2}[0em]
.
.
.
```

And on my `main.tex` I simply call it with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{mypreamble}
\begin{document}
My thesis.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.sty` is fine, and what I usually suggest but it makes no difference other than you need `\makeatletter` if you use commands with @ in the `\input` form.